# Failed to build docker image :

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I am trying to build docker image of my Spring Boot Application in eclipse.
Getting below error :

```
[INFO]  > Running creator

[INFO]     [creator]     ===> DETECTING
[INFO]     [creator]     5 of 18 buildpacks participating
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates   2.4.2
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica 8.9.0
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/executable-jar    5.3.1
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/dist-zip          4.3.0
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot       4.7.0
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> ANALYZING
[INFO]     [creator]     Previous image with name "docker.io/library/currency-exchange-service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT" not found
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> RESTORING
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> BUILDING
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]     Paketo CA Certificates Buildpack 2.4.2
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates
[INFO]     [creator]       Launch Helper: Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]         Creating /layers/paketo-buildpacks_ca-certificates/helper/exec.d/ca-certificates-helper
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]     Paketo BellSoft Liberica Buildpack 8.9.0
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica
[INFO]     [creator]       Build Configuration:
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_JVM_TYPE                 JRE             the JVM type - JDK or JRE
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_JVM_VERSION              11.*            the Java version
[INFO]     [creator]       Launch Configuration:
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_DEBUG_ENABLED           false           enables Java remote debugging support
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_DEBUG_PORT              8000            configure the remote debugging port
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_DEBUG_SUSPEND           false           configure whether to suspend execution until a debugger has attached
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_HEAP_DUMP_PATH                          write heap dumps on error to this path
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JAVA_NMT_ENABLED        true            enables Java Native Memory Tracking (NMT)
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JAVA_NMT_LEVEL          summary         configure level of NMT, summary or detail
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JFR_ARGS                                configure custom Java Flight Recording (JFR) arguments
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JFR_ENABLED             false           enables Java Flight Recording (JFR)
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JMX_ENABLED             false           enables Java Management Extensions (JMX)
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JMX_PORT                5000            configure the JMX port
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_HEAD_ROOM           0               the headroom in memory calculation
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_LOADED_CLASS_COUNT  35% of classes  the number of loaded classes in memory calculation
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_THREAD_COUNT        250             the number of threads in memory calculation
[INFO]     [creator]         $JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS                           the JVM launch flags
[INFO]     [creator]       BellSoft Liberica JRE 11.0.13: Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]         Downloading from https://github.com/bell-sw/Liberica/releases/download/11.0.13+8/bellsoft-jre11.0.13+8-linux-amd64.tar.gz
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to invoke layer creator
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to get dependency jre
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to download https://github.com/bell-sw/Liberica/releases/download/11.0.13+8/bellsoft-jre11.0.13+8-linux-amd64.tar.gz
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to request https://github.com/bell-sw/Liberica/releases/download/11.0.13+8/bellsoft-jre11.0.13+8-linux-amd64.tar.gz
[INFO]     [creator]     Get "https://github-releases.githubusercontent.com/115621629/4df6cd35-336d-4dc8-b743-d3fa53ca13c1?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20211123%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20211123T175918Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=22dff6886281392c0f4b285cf24867b219eb5ea8e5f12df914a960c7115843fe&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=115621629&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dbellsoft-jre11.0.13%2B8-linux-amd64.tar.gz&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
[INFO]     [creator]     ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  45.947 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-11-23T23:29:18+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.5.6:build-image (default-cli) on project currency-exchange-service: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.5.6:build-image failed: Builder lifecycle 'creator' failed with status code 145 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

I have springboot version : 2.5.6

Java version 17

I am currently going through this course : https://deloittedevelopment.udemy.com/course/microservices-with-spring-boot-and-spring-cloud/learn/lecture/24346750#questions/16133790

Practicing on laptop provided by my employer , maybe something to do with firewall.
If someone can confirm on this, or advice on the solution.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.in28minutes.microservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>currency-exchange-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>currency-exchange-service-docker</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <name>shubhamsdocker/mmv2-${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</name>
                    </image>
                    <pullPolicy>IF_NOT_PRESENT</pullPolicy>
                </configuration>                
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

As a workaround, I have manually created docker image with Dockerfile.

Comment: `Get "https://github-releases.githubusercontent.com/…": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority` suggests that maybe your CA certificates are out-of-date.

You can test your that your laptop can verify the certificate chain with the following
`openssl s_client -connect github-releases.githubusercontent.com:443`.

If that works, then the problem is probably in the Java keystore.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check
BellSoft Liberica JRE 11.0.13: Contributing to layer
Downloading from https://github.com/bell-sw/Liberica/releases/download/11.0.13+8/bellsoft-jre11.0.13+8-linux-amd64.tar.gz

Check previous releases in https://github.com/bell-sw/Liberica/releases/ to see if they are available, I didn't see the one you are using.

For the Cert check this:
https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-private-registry-x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority/21262/7

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in official documentation here https://docs.spring.io/spring-native/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/ :

> This is a generic error triggered by Docker and forwarded by Spring Boot Buildpacks support. native-image command has likely failed, so check the error messages in the output. If you can’t find anything, check if that’s not an out of memory error as described above.

Also make sure your java compiler version and the java version mentioned in pom.xml file are same.

Answer (score 0):

For Docker Desktop for Windows, set the DNS through the UI, by going to "settings -> Docker Engine" and add DNS list to the Docker daemon file "dns" : [ "1.1.1.1" , "8.8.8.8" ]

Answer (score 0):

I exactly had the same issue and it turned out to be a network connection. I switched my wifi connection with my alternate mobile internet and I was able to build the image. so it looks like my previous network was blocking  https://github.com/bell-sw/Liberica/releases/ URL. Hope this helps.